# Dynamic menu depending on a set mode

Tags: php

I am creating a dynamic menu whose items appear depending on a set 'mode' (that is passed via AJAX). Off this it creates the menu, disabling and hiding icons that are not associated with that mode.

The problem is, there are a lot of `if` conditions in my implementation. Can anyone show me a cleaner way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

```
public function gridMenu()
  {
    $mode = Validate::sanitize($_POST['mode']);

    $modes = array(
        'products' => array('edit', 'delete', 'archive')
    );

    $output = '<div id="hexContainer">';
    for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
      $img = '';
      $output .= '<div class="hex hex' . $i;
      if($i == 1)
      {
        if(in_array('edit', $modes[$mode]))
        {
          $output .= ' hex-selectable';
          $img = '<img data-option="Edit" src="' . ROOT . 'images/edit.png">';
        } else {
          $output .= ' hex-disabled';
        }
      }
      if($i == 2)
      {
        if(in_array('zzz', $modes[$mode]))
        {
          $output .= ' hex-selectable';
        } else {
          $output .= ' hex-disabled';
        }
      }
      if($i == 3)
      {
        if(in_array('delete', $modes[$mode]))
        {
          $output .= ' hex-selectable';
          $img = '<img data-option="Delete" src="' . ROOT . 'images/delete.png">';
        } else {
          $output .= ' hex-disabled';
        }
      }
      if($i == 4)
      {
        if(in_array('xxx', $modes[$mode]))
        {
          $output .= ' hex-selectable';
        } else {
          $output .= ' hex-disabled';
        }
      }
      if($i == 5)
      {
        if(in_array('archive', $modes[$mode]))
        {
          $output .= ' hex-selectable';
          $img = '<img data-option="Archive" src="' . ROOT . 'images/archive.png">';
        } else {
          $output .= ' hex-disabled';
        }
      }
      if($i == 6)
      {
        if(in_array('zzz', $modes[$mode]))
        {
          $output .= ' hex-selectable';
        } else {
          $output .= ' hex-disabled';
        }
      }

      $output .= '">';
      $output .= $img;
      $output .= '</div>';
    }
    $output .= '<div class="hex hex-mid"></div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    echo $output;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple bad practices.

There is no speration of concern. Your code is handling display, logic and controlling. All in onde function.

If I look at the function, it tells me it needs nothing (no arguments need to be passed in). So the only thing it should be using are variables that are accessible inside the object scope. BUT it turns out you are using a 'Validate' class and variables from the global scope ($_POST). I only know this because I read the entire code. No really nice towards other developers or the future you demaning that one should read the entire code before knowing how to use it and what is going on. And then ofcourse the biggest problem. al those if's

So, some problems and lets fix those problems.

You sanitize a variable that is handed in by the client ($_POST). You then create an array of possible 'modes' out of the blue. And after that you construct some html with images and a lot of business logic in it. Your function really has to be all knowing!

So, let's sepperate the concerns.

the `$mode` is clearly something the function needs to do it's magic. So this sould be a paramter that is passed in:

```
public function gridMenu(String $mode);
```

Note that the $mode needs to be a string. (obviously)

Another thing this function absolutely needs is the `$modes` variable. But, this variable doesn't change with every call of the `gridMenu()` function. It is the same, and should be, during runtime. But it could change over time or even change depending on what user is logged in. So we place this in the constructor of the class:

```
class Grid {

  private $modes;

  public function __construt($modes) {
    $this->$modes = $modes;
  }

  public function gridMenu(String $mode) { }
}
```

Now, gridMenu doesnt really say much. I would have to guess what it does: save a menu? does it create one? does it return one? So lets change that name to something more understandable:

```
class Grid {

  private $modes;

  public function __construt($modes) {
    $this->$modes = $modes;
  }

  public function renderMenu(String $mode) { }
}
```

Other possibilities are echoMenu, printMenu... Note that i left the word grid out because we are allready in the grid class. Obviously we wouldn't print a non-grid menu out here...

Good, so now we can remove that Validate::sanitize to the outside of the code and that declaration of $modes is no longer hard-coded into the class. This gives us a lot more flexibility,...

Now let's look at what our function does. It creates html. wheut? So it doesn't provide functionality but simply prints some html? So it's is actually a template disguised as a function... the sneaky bastard. We really have to keep an eye on those templates mate. They tend to creep into functions all the time all over the code.

This makes them harder to maintain and makes you write tons of Repeat-Yourself code. For instance if we would no want it to return the data in XML, or in a list instead of divs. Or even worse, have the delete button placed somewhere else, or or.... OOh boy, beter start all over again.

Needless to say, we are doing something really wrong here and we have read all this text for nothing :( Well atleast you know about sepration of concern. And I give you an oher link: [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

But what has this todo with you question? Ah it's very easy. What you actually need is a template that handles the display of of those '.hex' divs (what is a hex? and why is action.delete/archive a hex?). You also need some business logic that calculates what 'actions' you can do. and then we need some controller to bring it all together.

Your template would look something like this:

```
<div id="hexContainer">

  <div class="hex hex1 hex-<?php echo $mode->hasAction('edit') ? 'enabled' : 'disabled' ; ?>">
    <?php echo $mode->hasAction('edit') ? '<img data-option="Edit" src="' . ROOT . 'images/edit.png">': ''; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="hex hex2 hex-disabled">
    //zzz
  </div>

  <div class="hex hex1 hex-<?php echo $mode->hasAction('delete') ? 'enabled' : 'disabled' ; ?>">
    <?php echo $mode->hasAction('edit') ? '<img data-option="Edit" src="' . ROOT . 'images/delete.png">': ''; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="hex hex4 hex-disabled">
    //xxx
  </div>

  <div class="hex hex1 hex-<?php echo $mode->hasAction('archive') ? 'enabled' : 'disabled' ; ?>">
    <?php echo $mode->hasAction('edit') ? '<img data-option="Edit" src="' . ROOT . 'images/archive.png">': ''; ?>
  </div>

  <div class="hex hex6 hex-disabled">
    //zzz
  </div>

</div>
```

Your business logic 'Mode' and 'ModeFactory' class would look something like this:

```
class ModeFactory {

  private $modes;

  public function __construt(array $modes) {
    $this->$modes = $modes;
  }

  public function getMode(string $mode) {
    if ( !isset($this->modes[$mode]) ) {
      throw new ModeNotFoundException();
    }
    return new Mode($this->modes[$mode]);
  }
}

class Mode {
  private $actions = $actions;
  public function __construct(array $actions) {
    $this->actions = $actions;
  }
  public function hasAction(string $action) {
    return in_array($this->actions[$action]);
  }
}

class ModeNotFoundException extends Exception {}
```

NOTE: I used the Factory pattern here, is this the best? not, but it is a pattern that suited my needs and I feld like using it.

Then to bring it all togeter: the controller:

```
include 'Validate.php'; #the Validate class
include 'Mode.php'; #Modefactory and Mode

//note that now only the controller needs to know
// how the client communicates with this program
$currentMode = Validate::sanitize($_POST['mode']);

//because we pass in the modes+Actions in the factory,
// we can easily change everything.
//For instance we could fetch these mode+actions from a database
$modeFactory = new ModeFactory(array(
  'products'  =>  array('edit', 'delete', 'archive')
));

//we need this variable in the template so lets create it
$mode = $modeFactory->getMode($currentMode);

include 'myHexTemplate.php';

//all done
```

To sum up: the massive amount of if's wasn't the real problem. The real problem was the seperation of concern and those sneaky template functions. By solving those issues we now not only have better to read code. It is also very flexible, very easy to test etc etc.

Say we want to test a new Mode, we simply create our Mode:

```
$mode new Mode(array('myTestAction'));
```

Is this code perfect? no, the names used are horrible. What is a hex? what is a mode? what is an action? These are all generic words and make it very hard actualyl properly reuse this code. But appart from that, I think you get the important lesson here.

Good luck and fire away at the comments. @everyone else: feel free to correct spelling, I honestly don't feel like reading this entire post again for spelling mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive and detailed answer! As for templates, are they just stored somewhere as PHP/HTML files? Where would those go in a typical app in terms of directory structure?

Comment: @imperium2335 the most important thing when writing code is to think about your future self. In half a year, this code will stop working or will need some changes. And then you will have to know where to look. For instance templates, I would put them in /templates folder. Controllers in /controller and classes in /lib . there is however no real rule on where to put code. there are however some standards for OO code: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/0/ and yes. you store them as .php files